# Starting services (via GUI) makes front end unresponsive

Tags: c#, service, remote-desktop

I am unfortunately very new to C# programming and have never worked with GUI coding so I am probably following very bad practices. Here is a snip of what I am doing.

The overall goal was to pull status's from the machines so I can tell the front end if the service had started without actually remoting into the machine. Any suggestions would be helpful!

My apologies the code snip does not seem to be working well with my namespace and class call.

```
namespace General
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Password = "password";
            options.Username = "username";
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    public void Start(string programname)
    {
        textBox.Text = "Starting";
        ServiceController svc = new ServiceController("service name", "remote desktop name");
        svc.Start();
        svc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timer1);
        if (svc.Status == ServiceContrllerStatus.Running)
        {
            textBox8.Text = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
        textBox8.Text = "Fail";
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start(button.Text);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It will wait for that Thread to first respond or timeout before the code will execute further. Put your code in a `Thread t1 = new Thread(()=>{ //code here });` This will allow your code to run, and remember to add `t1.Start();`

Comment: I complete forgot to mention in my post about the title. When I use this code, my front end is frozen until the status comes back.

Comment: You're locking your main thread responsible for presentation. Do your task in a thread and report back the results. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: I am also new to threading for C#, I have done it once in C++. Is there any differences besides t1.Start();?

Comment: Check out my answer below; believe it will resolve your screen freezing

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            ServiceController svc = new ServiceController("service name", "remote desktop name");
            svc.Start();
            svc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timer1);
            if (svc.Status == ServiceContrllerStatus.Running)
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                { //This is required to acccess the Main UI Thread If you don't do this you will get and error
                    textBox8.Text = "Success";
                });

            }
            else
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    textBox8.Text = "Fail";
                });

            }
        });
        myThread.Start();
```

Comment: Sorry, this may sound like a stupid question but I just use myThread.Start(); to call it in the button click?

Comment: Yes you can, but then you have to make the Thread a global varaible.

Comment: Just put the `myThread.Start()` in the `Start` Method just after your `Thread` code.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try

Comment: I have attempted implementing the code but I have run into an issue. Dispatcher is coming up as not existing. I have System.Threading; and System.Windows.Forms; am I missing something?

Comment: Believe Dispatcher does not exist in windows forms. I am not sure what to use then and if it require to use anything at all then.